# HTML/CSS: How to make paragraphs when text content is overflowing?+more problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, overflow

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,"666666666666666666666+3=123456678"];
var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
        table.border = '0';
        table.appendChild(tableBody);
        
function makeArr()
{
        var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myTable1");
        tableBody.innerHTML = "";
            
        for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
            tableBody.appendChild(tr);
            
        var td = document.createElement('TD')
            td.width = '275';
            
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

            tr.appendChild(td);
            myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
        }
        
    var z = document.getElementById("myTable1");
    var tablewidth = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("myTable2")).getPropertyValue('width');
    var tableheight = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("myTable2")).getPropertyValue('height');
    z.style.height = tableheight;
    z.style.width = tablewidth;
}
```

```css
#myTable1,
#myTable2{
    background: #EEEEEB;
    width: 100;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#myTable1 td,
#myTable2 td{
    text-align: right;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<input type="button"value="MakeTable"onClick="makeArr()">
<div class="tables" id="tables" >
    <div id="myTable1">

    </div>
    
    <table id="myTable2">
    <th>Always here,same size</th>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Hey guys!
I hope someone can help me with a couple questions/problems:)

The main objective is to make ***myTable1*** the same size of ***myTable2***(which is supposed to have always the same size). If ***myTable1*** overflows in width, I want it to make a new paragraph with the content and If it overflows in height, just make it scrollable.
Does this even work with css overflow(I didnt find anything to put the content in a new paragraph)?

- Why does it display the 666...6 as 666...0 and how to prevent it?
- How to prevent the size of ***myTable2*** and therefore ***myTable1*** from changing and the formatting from getting wrong, when increasing the amount of content in the **th** of ***myTable2***?
- What is wrong, why can't I even make it scrollable?
- How to format the two tables to be on the left for example, without using float: left; and therefore it exitting the body?

Sorry for the many questions and confusion...Im also very open for any other usefull suggestions and help=)

Answer (score 1):

A few things :

- remove `float: left` from `#myTable1, #myTable2` and add `display: flex` to `.tables`
- add `word-break: break-all` to `#myTable1 td, #myTable2 td`
- add `overflow: auto` to `#myTable1, #myTable2`
- you can't make `table`, `tr`, `td` **scrollable** by using `overflow: auto` or `scroll`, you have to use it on `div`, `span`
- you are getting 0 after your 66666666666666666 because you are reaching **max value** [https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_max_value.asp#:~:text=The%20MAX_VALUE%20property%20returns%20the,MAX_VALUE%20are%20represented%20as%20infinity](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_max_value.asp#:%7E:text=The%20MAX_VALUE%20property%20returns%20the,MAX_VALUE%20are%20represented%20as%20infinity).

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,"666666666666666666666+3=123456678"];
var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
        table.border = '0';
        table.appendChild(tableBody);
        
function makeArr()
{
        var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myTable1");
        tableBody.innerHTML = "";
            
        for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
            tableBody.appendChild(tr);
            
        var td = document.createElement('TD')
            td.width = '275';
            
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

            tr.appendChild(td);
            myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
        }
        
    var z = document.getElementById("myTable1");
    var tablewidth = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("myTable2")).getPropertyValue('width');
    var tableheight = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("myTable2")).getPropertyValue('height');
    z.style.width = tablewidth;
    z.style.height = tableheight;
}
```

```css
.tables {
  display: flex;
}

#myTable1,
#myTable2{
    background: #EEEEEB;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto
}

#myTable1 td,
#myTable2 td{
    text-align: right;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<input type="button"value="MakeTable"onClick="makeArr()">
<div class="tables" id="tables" >
    <div id="myTable1">

    </div>
    
    <div id="myTable2">
      <table id="myTable2">
      <th>Always here,same size</th>
          <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          </tr>

      </table>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick answer:)) I did strictly as you said, the word break works only for  words? Sorry for my bad explanation, i changed the string ... there will be strings like "123456789+123456789=123456789" where each individual number separated by symbols has a maximum lenght, which will be round about the width of myTable1, and the paragraphs have to come after the width is reached. the word break didnt work for the 6666666...I only want to scroll down, not left and right, also now the background of myTable1 is always visible.Sorry for the essay :D

Comment: especially the word break doesnt work as intended, it makes me scroll, im trying now on a new example

Comment: I added a snippet

Comment: wow ok thanks im gonna compare what went wrong on my part

Comment: I wrapped the second table in a div too :)

Comment: Works perfectly fine =) I wanted to wrap it anyway, like the other..but now shouldnt the seconds table not have an ID, since the first one neither has one? or is there a specific reason for the div and the table to have both the same ID?

Comment: OH... and another, yet important and more JS question... I want the line break to be after one of a couple specific characters if a given length is reached, beats me completely how to do it...

Comment: One small Problem: myTable2 changes in size, its supposed to be scrollable when overflowing on the vertical

Comment: it should be okay now

Comment: Jupp perfect thanksss=) I will open a new question on how to break the line after specific characters if a given length is reached, the contents of the table alway have a similar pattern as 1+1=2, 2-2=0, 300000*3=900000 and so on

Comment: you'll need javascript for that imho